# How can I make a proper loop for this case

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying for a bootcamp project to scrape data from the following website: https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/bitcoin/historical_data/usd?start_date=2021-01-01&end_date=2021-09-30. My aim is to get separate lists for the following columns: Date, Market Cap, volume, Open, and Close. My problem is, that for the columns Market Cap, volume, open and close, the class name (text-center) is the same:

```
<td class="text-center">
$161,716,193,676
</td>
<td class="text-center">
$16,571,161,476
</td>
<td class="text-center">
$1,340.02
</td>
<td class="text-center">
N/A
</td>
```

I've tried to solve it with this:

```
import requests

url_get = requests.get('https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/ethereum/historical_data#panel')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

soup = BeautifulSoup(url_get.content,"html.parser")

table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'card-block'})

row = table.find_all('th', attrs={'class':'font-semibold text-center'})
```

row_length = len(row)
row_length

```
temp = []

for i in range(0, row_length):

Date = table.find_all('th', attrs={'class':'font-semibold text-center'})[i].text

Market_Cap = table.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'text-center'})[i].text
Market_Cap = Market_Cap.strip()

Volume = table.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'text-center'})[i].text
Volume = Market_Cap.strip()

Open = table.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'text-center'})[i].text
Open = Open.strip()

Close = table.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'text-center'})[i].text
Close = Close.strip()

temp.append((Date,Market_Cap,Volume,Open,Close))

temp
```

and the output was looking as frustrating like this:

```
[('2022-09-29',
'$161,716,193,676',
'$161,716,193,676',
'$161,716,193,676',
('2022-09-28',
'$16,571,161,476',
'$16,571,161,476',
'$16,571,161,476',
'$16,571,161,476'),
```

(and on)

I need to do it with the row length method (which is 31 according to my code), but since the code is not identical, i suppose i can't get the output as i wanted. it would much appreciated if anyone could help me figure it out. cheers

Answer (score 0):

soup.find_all('td',class_= 'text-center').text